# How do I get the product image url from a product collection?

Tags: magento

I need to re-size an image for an XML feed. I am looping through the products fine but when trying to get the URL of a re-sized image I am running into problems.

```
foreach ($collection as $_product) {

$MainImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(false)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(true)
->keepTransparency(true)->resize(300, 150);

$arr['Image'] = $_product->getSmallImageUrl();
$arr['MainImage'] = $MainImage;
$arr['Name'] = $_product->getName();

}
```

If I echo out $MainImage it returns a URL, but for some reason it doesn't like being in a string.

Basically if I then echo out the array it does not show the URL of the image, it's just blank.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look @ /app/design/frontend/default/base/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');

....   
foreach ($collection as $_product) {
    $MainImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(410,420);
    $MainImage = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $MainImage, 'small_image');
```

or cast the return as string

```
$MainImage = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(false)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(true)->keepTransparency(true)->resize(300, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

> $arr['MainImage'] = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image');?